# Два слайдера slick, один скрыт

Tags: jquery, slider, slick.js

Использую на странице два слайдера slick, один из которых имеет css-класс .active, второй без этого класса. Слайдер без класса active должен быть скрыт с помощью display none.
При нажатии на кнопку, классы active должны меняться у этих слайдеров.
Но проблема в том, что при смене класса active, второй слайдер остаётся не видимым, т.е. класс slick-track имеет width: 0px, которые устанавливает сам слайдер.
Подскажите, как правильно инициализировать два слайдера, чтобы по нажатию на кнопку скрывать один из слайдеров и второй был виден?

```
https://jsfiddle.net/8qLfgme0/
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script
            src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"
            integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44="
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick-theme.min.css">
    <style>
    .wrap{
        display: none;
    }
    .wrap.active{
        display: block;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="wrap active"  data-tab="cars">
            <div class="tab-slider cars">
                <div>slide1</div>
                <div>slide2</div>
                <div>slide3</div>
                <div>slide4</div>
                <div>slide5</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="wrap"  data-tab="electro">
            <div class="tab-slider electro">
                <div>slide1</div>
                <div>slide2</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button class="btn">click</button>

<script>
    $(function(){

    $('.tab-slider').slick({
        infinite: true,
        slidesToShow: 2,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        dots: true
    });

    $('.btn').on('click', function(e){
        var $tabContent = $('.tab-content'),
            $active = $tabContent.find('.wrap.active'),
            $wrap = $tabContent.find('.wrap');
        $wrap.toggleClass('active');
    })

    })
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Надо код фрагментом прикреплять

Comment: сделал фрагментом, есть ли идеи, как сделать слайдер?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script
            src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"
            integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44="
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick-theme.min.css">
    <style>
    .wrap{
        display: none;
    }
    .wrap.active{
        display: block;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="wrap active" data-show="true" data-tab="cars">
            <div class="tab-slider cars">
                <div>slide1</div>
                <div>slide2</div>
                <div>slide3</div>
                <div>slide4</div>
                <div>slide5</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="wrap" data-show="false" data-tab="electro">
            <div class="tab-slider electro">
                <div>img1</div>
                <div>img2</div>
                <div>img3</div>
                <div>img4</div>
                <div>img5</div>
                <div>img6</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button class="btn">click</button>

<script>
;(function (slider, button){
   slider.slick({
      infinite: true,
      slidesToShow: 2,
      slidesToScroll: 1,
      dots: true
   });

   var content = $('.tab-content');

   content.find('[data-show="true"]').addClass('active');

   button.on('click', function () {
      content.find('[data-show]').each(function(i, v){
         v.dataset.show =  v.dataset.show !== 'true';
         if (v.dataset.show === 'true') {
            v.classList.add("active");
            v.children[0].slick.setPosition();
         }
         else
            v.classList.remove("active");
      });
   });
})($('.tab-slider'), $('.btn'));
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Но проблема в том, что при смене класса active, второй слайдер остаётся не видимым, т.е. класс slick-track имеет width: 0px... ща

Comment: если нажать на кнопку, тогда слайды второго слайдера наложены друг на друга.

Comment: v.children[0].slick.setPosition();  - DOM элемент.
$(v.children[0]).slick('setPosition');  - jQuery объект,
вроде работает

Answer (score 0):

Можно скрывать слайдер с сохранением ширины при помощи `position:absolute`

```js
$('.tab-slider').slick({
    slidesToShow: 2,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    dots: true
});
$('.btn').click(function(){
  $('.wrapper').toggleClass('hidden');
})
```

```css
.tab-content{
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.wrapper.hidden{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  z-index:-1;
  opacity:0;
}
.slick-slide{
  height:50px;
  line-height:50px;
  text-align:center;
  font-weight:bold;
  background-color:#cda;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  border:1px dotted;
}
.cars .slick-slide{
  background-color:#acd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick-theme.min.css">

<div class="tab-content">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="tab-slider electro">
      <div>slide1</div>
      <div>slide2</div>
      <div>slide3</div>
      <div>slide4</div>
      <div>slide5</div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="wrapper hidden">
    <div class="tab-slider cars">
      <div>img1</div>
      <div>img2</div>
      <div>img3</div>
      <div>img4</div>
      <div>img5</div>
      <div>img6</div>
    </div>
   </div>
</div>
<button class="btn">click</button>
```